# MVC4 Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

I need to pass values from three dropdownlists to the controller when user selects some value from any one of the dropdownlist.i tried like this but the value from only the dropdown selected is passed others are null values ,any help would be appreciated.

VIEW

```
      @@using (Html.BeginForm("GetFilterValues","Home",FormMethod.gET))
          {   
            @Html.DropDownList("FClass", ViewBag.Market as SelectList,  new { id = "Market" , onchange = "$(this).parents('form').submit();" })
           }

      @using (Html.BeginForm("GetFilterValues","Home",FormMethod.Get))
                    {
                          @Html.DropDownList("FClass", ViewBag.Class as SelectList,  new { id = "FClass" , onchange = "$(this).parents('form').submit();" })
                      }

              </td>
                        <td>
                 @Html.Label("Status")
                            </td>
               <td>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("GetFilterValues","Home",FormMethod.Get))
                    {
                                                 @Html.DropDownList("Status", ViewBag.Status as SelectList,  new { id = "Status" , onchange = "$(this).parents('form').submit();" })

                    }
```

CONTROLLER
            [HttpgET]

```
      public void GetFilterValues()
       {
        string  market = this.Request.Form.Get("Market");
        string fclass = this.Request.Form.Get("FClass");
        string status = this.Request.Form.Get("Status");
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried using fiddler to see what is actually being sent?

Comment: you want them all in one form. otherwise they will NOT be submitted together.

Answer (score 0):

Try a single form trough a POST and pull the values by name using a FormCollection like this...

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetFilterValues","Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {     
          @Html.DropDownList("nameMarket", ViewBag.Market as SelectList,  new { id = "Market" , onchange = "$(this).parents('form').submit();" })
          @Html.DropDownList("nameClass", ViewBag.Class as SelectList,  new { id = "FClass" , onchange = "$(this).parents('form').submit();" })
          @Html.DropDownList("nameStatus", ViewBag.Status as SelectList,  new { id = "Status" , onchange = "$(this).parents('form').submit();" })
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public void GetFilterValues(FormCollection collection) {
    string  market = Convert.ToString(collection["nameMarket"]);
    string fclass = Convert.ToString(collection["nameClass"]);
    string status = Convert.ToString(collection["nameStatus"]);
}
```